# Error: (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')) Mac M1

Tags: java, maven, gis, arcgis

Apologies for the question if it was answered, as I am a new to this platform. Can you refer me to the post if this question was answered before.

I am trying to implement https://github.com/Esri/java-maven-starter-project. I have downloaded the source code and followed the outlined step, however, I keep getting the below error message when I am at the 6th step (In the Maven view, run the compile phase under Lifecycle and then the exec:java goal to run the app.), precisely, exec:java.

I am running on Mac M1 chip, and when I followed this tutorial (https://github.com/Esri/java-maven-starter-project), I was not able to to compile exec:java, the last step. I am getting the below message when I tried to do it. Is it possible to direct me on what should I do in order to run the app on my machine?

/Users/..../.arcgis/100.13.0/jniLibs/OSX64/libruntimecore.dylib: dlopen(/Users/..../.arcgis/100.13.0/jniLibs/OSX64/libruntimecore.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/..../.arcgis/100.13.0/jniLibs/OSX64/libruntimecore.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libruntimecore.dylib' (no such file)

Further information, I am working in IntelliJ.

**EDIT**
Apparently, arcgis does not support arc64 chips. The error is caused because it tried to load an x64 dylib into arc64. You may circumvent this issue by esri response below: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-java-questions/error-mach-o-file-but-is-an-incompatible/m-p/1151796#M2568

Comment: You need an Arm64 Java probably

Comment: @g00se: that's not at all probable, when the error message clearly identifies an arcgis-supplied JNI file as the problem. Probably arcgis hasn't been updated for the new Macs yet. https://guides.library.jhu.edu/gis/software-access/mac suggests not.

Comment: Indeed, arcgis doesn't currently support apple M1 chips. I have checked the referred dylib, which turned out to be on x64, which generated the above error. Apparently, it tried to load x64 into arc64. You may circumvent this issue by esri response below: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-java-questions/error-mach-o-file-but-is-an-incompatible/m-p/1151796#M2568

Comment: Sorry - didn't read carefully enough

Answer (score 0):

There was similar problem with **de.mkammerer.argon2** library.

I added in **pom.xml** follow dependency:

```xml
<dependency>  
    <groupId>de.mkammerer</groupId>  
    <artifactId>argon2-jvm</artifactId>  
    <version>2.11</version>  
</dependency>
```

It solved the problem

Comment: I don't think this would be a solution since de.mkammerer is specific to a certain library

Comment: Maybe. I just had similar problem recently and solved it this way. I decided to write about it, maybe it will help someone too)